# define a diagonal matrix from a matrix, with products of subdiagonals

Tags: python, numpy

How could I construct a diagonal matrix D from a matrix A where:

- the first element of the diagonal matrix D must be the product of all elements in the subdiagonal of the matrix A
- the second element in the diagonal matrix D must be the product of all elements in the subdiagonal of the matrix A except the first one
- the third element in the diagonal matrix D must be the product of all elements in the subdiagonal of the matrix A except the first and the second one
- ... and the last element of the diagonal matrix D must be 1

Comment: Please post a minimal example input and output, and what have you tried. Are you using pure Python, NumPy, something else?

Comment: subdiagonals can be exracted via numpy.diag and the product of the elements can be computed by numpy.prod. Please post an example of your input/output

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach:

```
def subdiag_prod_(a):
    sub_diag = np.diagonal(a, offset=-1)
    mask = np.triu(np.ones((sub_diag.shape*2))).astype('bool')
    m = sub_diag[:,None].T * mask
    ma = np.ma.array(sub_diag[:,None].T * mask, mask=~mask)
    diag = np.prod(ma, axis=1).data
    out = np.diag(diag)
    last_row = np.zeros([out.shape[0]+1]*2)
    last_row[:out.shape[0], :out.shape[1]] += out
    return last_row
```

---

```
a = np.random.randint(1,5,(10,10))

array([[2, 2, 1, 4, 3, 1, 3, 1, 4, 4],
       [2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2],
       [4, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4],
       [3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3],
       [1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4],
       [4, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1, 3, 2],
       [4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 1, 4, 3, 1],
       [1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1],
       [1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1]])

subdiag_prod(a)

array([[288.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0., 144.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,  72.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,  24.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  24.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,  24.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   6.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   6.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   2.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   1.]])
```

---

**Details**

The first step is to take the ndarray's subdiagonal with `np.diagonal`:

```
sub_diag = np.diagonal(a, offset=-1)
# array([2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 3, 2])
```

We can create a `mask` by using `np.tril`, which we can then use to take the product of the subdiagonal elements i the specified fashion:

```
mask = np.triu(np.ones((sub_diag.shape*2))).astype('bool')
```

Now we can create a masked array, using the above `ndarray` as mask, by multiplying the mask and the subdiagonal:

```
mask = np.ma.array(sub_diag[:,None].T * mask, mask=~mask)
```

Now we can take the row-wise product of the masked array:

```
d = np.prod(ma, axis=1).data
# array([288, 144,  72,  24,  24,  24,   6,   6,   2])
```

And then simply build a digonal matrix from it:

```
out = np.diag(d)
last_row = np.zeros([out.shape[0]+1]*2)
last_row[:out.shape[0], :out.shape[1]] += out
```

Comment: Last element must be 1

Comment: Its the subdiagonal not the diagonal though @MadPhysicist

Comment: According to OP: "and the last element of the diagonal matrix D must be 1". This is why you shouldn't answer poorly specified questions with incomplete information.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with your answer btw. It makes perfect sense. The question doesn't though

Comment: Oh thanks, I totally missed that @MadPhysicist. The thing is that it seemed like a fun problem to solve, and though it is completely lacking a mcve, the question statement seems clear enough

Comment: Yeah. I know the feeling